# Assigning global variable that is pickable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I aplogize if this is an easy problem to fix, I've tried searching but couldn't come up with a solution. I come from PHP, so maybe what I am trying to achieve is not possible, or it needs to be done differently in python.

Okay, so I have a class called `database.py` which parses a config file and depending on what 'database' type I am using returns an object of either `sqlite` or `mysql`

**database.py**

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import pooling


class Database:

    # Connect to the database
    @staticmethod
    def connect():
        if Config().type() == 'mysql':
            return mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(**Config().mysql())
        elif Config().type() == 'sqlite':
            return sqlite3.connect("%s.sqlite" % Config().sqlite())
```

So, as you can see, I am returning an object of the database I am using, for this example, let's say `Config().type() == 'mysql'` is true, and we are using `mysql`, and the `Config().mysql()` is just a dictionary like so:

```
{
    'pool_name': "indexit",
    'pool_size': config['DATABASE']['mysql']['pool_size'],
    'pool_reset_session': True,
    'user': config['DATABASE']['mysql']['user'],
    'password': config['DATABASE']['mysql']['password'],
    'host': config['DATABASE']['mysql']['host'],
    'database': config['DATABASE']['mysql']['database'],
    'auth_plugin': 'mysql_native_password',
    'charset': 'utf8',
    'use_unicode': True
}
```

In my main python file, I am trying to assign the `Database.connect()` to a variable, and then use it in my threaded function and get the mysql pool from the object:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from core.database import Database

class Indexit:

    # MyProgram constructor
    def __init__(self):
        # 1 connection for threads
        self.database = Database.connect()

    # Thread to run
    def run(self, id):
        # return the id
        print(id)

        # Get the database pool
        print(self.database.get_connection())

    # Do the threads
    def main(self):
        # Pool connections
        with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
            pool.map(self.run, range(10000000))

Indexit().main()
```

But my code returns an error: (you can view the full code here: https://github.com/filtration/indexit)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "indexit.py", line 75, in <module>
    Indexit().main()
  File "indexit.py", line 68, in main
    pool.map(self.run, range(10000000))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

So, my question is, how can I use the global connection and then use my threaded function to get their own pool worker?

Comment: Where the error is coming from? I don't see any pickle reference in your code.

Comment: @DanielLima updated OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `MySQLConnectionPool` uses threads internally. When you invoke the `map` method of a `multiprocessing.Pool`, it tries to send everything that is needed to run the given function. In this case *including* the database connection pool.

When a new process is created, it only has *one thread*. So it doesn't make sense to try and send threading related stuff like locks to a child process. Whatever data that lock has would be meaningless in the child process. Hence the error.

You should probably create the database connection *inside* the pool worker or inside the initializer for the `Pool`.